# Python UTF-8 Lowercase Turkish Specific Letter

Tags: python, unicode, encoding, utf-8

with using python 2.7:

```
>myCity = 'Isparta'
>myCity.lower()
>'isparta'
#-should be-
>'ısparta'
```

tried some decoding, (like, myCity.decode("utf-8").lower()) but could not find how to do it.

how can lower this kinds of letters? ('I' > 'ı', 'İ' > 'i' etc)

EDIT: In Turkish, lower case of 'I' is 'ı'. Upper case of 'i' is 'İ'

Comment: Is that an ASCII capital letter Eye? If it's some non-ASCII character that *looks* like an ASCII character, it would be wise to name it unambigously (for example, by including the code point).

Comment: it is the ASCII capital letter, I.

Comment: Is there a language wherein the lowercase version of ASCII capital I ("I") is something other than ASCII lowercase I ("i")? otherwise, I'm horribly confused by this question, because what you are showing is exactly the proper behavior.

Comment: @KenB: Turkish for example. Which is why that culture is [a common test for i18n-proofing code that compares user input with string literals](http://www.moserware.com/2008/02/does-your-code-pass-turkey-test.html).

Comment: @Jeff Atwood once write about that, it is better you read [this article](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2008/03/whats-wrong-with-turkey.html) Also, this is the best article written about the Turkish Locale I guess.

Comment: Well that is just darn interesting. I learned something new today. @FallenAngel, great link

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Some have suggested using the `tr_TR.utf8` locale. At least on Ubuntu, perhaps related to [this bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/langpack-locales/+bug/818770), setting this locale does not produce the desired result:

```
import locale
locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, 'tr_TR.utf8')

myCity = u'Isparta İsparta'
print(myCity.lower())
# isparta isparta
```

So if this bug affects you, as a workaround you could perform this translation yourself:

```
lower_map = {
    ord(u'I'): u'ı',
    ord(u'İ'): u'i',
    }

myCity = u'Isparta İsparta'
lowerCity = myCity.translate(lower_map)
print(lowerCity)
# ısparta isparta
```

prints

```
ısparta isparta
```

Comment: There is one, actually.

Comment: Obviously this is a late comment, but at least for python 3.7, there is no locale sensitive case comparison. See [here](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/locale.html#background-details-hints-tips-and-caveats) on the locale page.

Answer (score 10):

You should use new derived class from unicode from [emre's solution](https://github.com/emre/unicode_tr)

```
class unicode_tr(unicode):
    CHARMAP = {
        "to_upper": {
            u"ı": u"I",
            u"i": u"İ",
        },
        "to_lower": {
            u"I": u"ı",
            u"İ": u"i",
        }
    }

    def lower(self):
        for key, value in self.CHARMAP.get("to_lower").items():
            self = self.replace(key, value)
        return self.lower()

    def upper(self):
        for key, value in self.CHARMAP.get("to_upper").items():
            self = self.replace(key, value)
        return self.upper()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print unicode_tr("kitap").upper()
    print unicode_tr("KİTAP").lower()
```

Gives

```
KİTAP
kitap
```

This must solve your problem.

Comment: Note that [link-only answers are discouraged](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/link-only-answers/info), SO answers should be the end-point of a search for a solution (vs. yet another stopover of references, which tend to get stale over time). Please consider adding a stand-alone synopsis here, keeping the link as a reference.

Answer (score 2):

You can just use .replace() function before changing to upper/lower. In your case:

```
    myCity.replace('I', 'ı').lower()
```

Answer (score 1):

I forked and redesigned Emre's solution by monkey-patching method to built-in unicode module. The advantage of this new approach is no need to use a subclass of unicode and 
redefining unicode strings by `my_unicode_string = unicode_tr(u'bla bla bla')`
Just importing this module, integrates seamlessly with builtin native unicode strings

https://github.com/technic-programming/unicode_tr

```
# -*- coding: utf8 -*-
# Redesigned by @guneysus

import __builtin__
from forbiddenfruit import curse

lcase_table = tuple(u'abcçdefgğhıijklmnoöprsştuüvyz')
ucase_table = tuple(u'ABCÇDEFGĞHIİJKLMNOÖPRSŞTUÜVYZ')

def upper(data):
    data = data.replace('i',u'İ')
    data = data.replace(u'ı',u'I')
    result = ''
    for char in data:
        try:
            char_index = lcase_table.index(char)
            ucase_char = ucase_table[char_index]
        except:
            ucase_char = char
        result += ucase_char
    return result

def lower(data):
    data = data.replace(u'İ',u'i')
    data = data.replace(u'I',u'ı')
    result = ''
    for char in data:
        try:
            char_index = ucase_table.index(char)
            lcase_char = lcase_table[char_index]
        except:
            lcase_char = char
        result += lcase_char
    return result

def capitalize(data):
    return data[0].upper() + data[1:].lower()

def title(data):
    return " ".join(map(lambda x: x.capitalize(), data.split()))

curse(__builtin__.unicode, 'upper', upper)
curse(__builtin__.unicode, 'lower', lower)
curse(__builtin__.unicode, 'capitalize', capitalize)
curse(__builtin__.unicode, 'title', title)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print u'istanbul'.upper()
    print u'İSTANBUL'.lower()
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the proper locale (I'm guessing tr-TR) with `locale.setLocale()`. Otherwise the default upper-lower mappings will be used, and if that default is en-US, the lowercase version of `I` is `i`.

Comment: I downvoted this answer because setting the locale to `tr_TR` does not change the behavior of `str.upper`/`str.lower` on the letters `i`/`I`.