# Iterate over utf-8 characters in python

Tags: python, utf-8, character-encoding, python-3.6

I am using python 3.6 to read a file encoded in utf-8, in Spanish (thus, including letter ñ). I open the file with the utf-8 codec, and it loads correctly: while debugging, I can see ñ in the loaded text.

However, when I iterate over characters, ñ is read as two characters, n and ~. Concretely, when I run:

```
for c in text:
        hexc = int(hex(ord(c)), 16)
        if U_LETTERS[lang][0] <= hexc <= U_LETTERS[lang][1] \
            or hexc in U_LETTERS[lang][2:] \
            or hexc == U_SPACE:
                filtered_text+=c
```

and text includes an ñ, the variable c takes it as an n (and therefore, hexc is 110 instead of 241), and then it takes ~ (and hexc is 771). I guess there is an internal conversion to an 8 bit char when iterating in this way.  What is the proper way to do this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19030948/python-utf-8-lowercase-turkish-specific-letter) should lead you to the solution

Comment: I can't reproduce this problem in Python 3.6.0. Can you post a string that does this conversion? BTW, why are you converting `ord(c)` to a hex string and then back to an int?

Comment: Thanks Adelin, but this happens also when I don't lowercase (maybe I should have removed that line in the example).

Comment: @PM 2Ring it happens with any string that contains ñ (e.g. añorar).

Comment: @rgalhama The question remains: Why are you converting `ord(c)` to a hex string and then back to an int?

Comment: because:

        if U_LETTERS[lang][0] <= hexc <= U_LETTERS[lang][1] \
                or hexc in U_LETTERS[lang][2:] \
                or hexc == U_SPACE:
            filtered_text+=c

(but let me know if there is a better option)

Comment: `hexc = int(hex(ord(c)), 16)` gives the same result as `hexc = ord(c)`; clearly the second expression is more efficient.

Comment: It tried your code on `'añorar'` and it behaves like I expect: the `ñ` is preserved, and the codepoint number returned by `ord` is 241, not 110. Can we assume your terminal is set to use UTF-8? Does `sys.getdefaultencoding()` return 'utf-8'? To perform that last test you need to import `sys`.

Comment: The `hexc` value of `n` is `110`, of `ñ` `241` in my test environment. The problem is not this conversion.

Comment: it does return utf-8, and yet it returns 110 for ñ...

Comment: actually it processes first n and then the symbol ~, so I guess it is breaking the string into 8 bit chars

Comment: Then this is probably concerned with [Unicode normalisation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_equivalence#Normalization). Is the codepoint of '~' 771?

Comment: @lenz indeed that's the codepoint I am getting for ~

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This has to do with Unicode normalisation. The letter "ñ" can be expressed either with a single character with the codepoint 0xF1 (241), or with the two character "n" and a combining character for the superposed tilde, ie. the codepoints 0x6E and 0x0303 (110 and 771).

These two ways of expressing the letter are considered *equivalent*; however, they are not the same in string comparison.
Python provides functionality to convert from one form to the other by means of the `unicodedata` module.
The first form is called *composed* (NFC), the second one *decomposed* (NFD) normalised form.

An example explains it the easiest way:

```
>>> import unicodedata
>>> '\xf1'
'ñ'
>>> [ord(c) for c in '\xf1']
[241]
>>> [ord(c) for c in unicodedata.normalize('NFD', '\xf1')]
[110, 771]
>>> [ord(c) for c in unicodedata.normalize('NFC', 'n\u0303')]
[241]
>>>
```

So, to solve your problem, convert all of the text to the desired normalisation form before any further processing.

> Note: Unicode normalisation is a problem separate from encoding. You can have this with UTF16 or UTF32 just as well. In the decomposed form, you actually have two (or more) characters (each of which might be represented with multiple bytes, depending on the encoding). It's up the displaying device (the terminal emulator, an editor...) to show this as a single letter with marks above/below the base character.