# Custom str function raises type error in regex search

Tags: regex, python-3.x

I am trying to create new str class in python to handle correctly uppercase, title etc as its not understanding the language the text written. I need some special cases for characters in Turkish like, i -> İ, İ -> i.

For starting point i create sample class and do some test as below

```
 import builtins
 class gstr(str):
     def title(self, lang = "en"):
         if lang == "en":
             return self.title()
         elif lang == "tr":
              return self.title()

 koy = "Modiyes".lower()
 print(koy.title(), type(koy))
 builtins.str = gstr
 koy = "Modiyes".lower()
 print(koy.title(), type(koy))

 re.search(r"{}".format(koy), "aaa Modiyes bbb")
```

I haven't done any manipulation yet, but when i tried the new string class, it throws **TypeError: first argument must be string or compiled pattern** in regex search. but it prints it properly, and type(koy) shows `<class 'str'>` for both class. I couldn't understand what can it be the problem for regex to throw this error, any idea?
Thanks a lot.

Comment: Also, check this question, there are several solutions and implementations for what you are trying to achieve: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19030948/python-utf-8-lowercase-turkish-specific-letter

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't figure out to make with class, so that, I decide to define separate function for each case with re, as follows which works pretty good, if someone needs i hope it will help.

```
import re

def tr_upper(text):
    text = re.sub(r"i", "İ", text)
    text = re.sub(r"ı", "I", text)
    text = re.sub(r"ç", "Ç", text)
    text = re.sub(r"ş", "Ş", text)
    text = re.sub(r"ü", "Ü", text)
    text = re.sub(r"ğ", "Ğ", text)
    text = text.upper() 
    return text

def tr_title(text):
    text = re.sub(r"\bi", "İ", text)
    text = re.sub(r"\bı", "I", text)
    text = re.sub(r"\bç", "Ç", text)
    text = re.sub(r"\bş", "Ş", text)
    text = re.sub(r"\bü", "Ü", text)
    text = re.sub(r"\bğ", "Ğ", text)
    text = text.title() 
    return text

def tr_capital(text):
    text = re.sub(r"^i", "İ", text)
    text = re.sub(r"^ı", "I", text)
    text = re.sub(r"^ç", "Ç", text)
    text = re.sub(r"^ş", "Ş", text)
    text = re.sub(r"^ü", "Ü", text)
    text = re.sub(r"^ğ", "Ğ", text)
    text = text.capitalize()
    return text

def tr_lower(text):
    text = re.sub(r"İ", "i", text)
    text = re.sub(r"I", "ı", text)
    text = re.sub(r"Ç", "ç", text)
    text = re.sub(r"Ş", "ş", text)
    text = re.sub(r"Ü", "ü", text)
    text = re.sub(r"Ğ", "ğ", text)
    text = text.lower() 
    return text
```