# How Can I upper the word 'i' to 'İ'?

Tags: python, django, string, django-models

in my project there is a profile that name is "İsmet".

When Django try to search it with the following code, return empty.

```
Profile.objects.filter(name__icontains='i')
```

[image]

But when I try this return correctly;

```
Profile.objects.filter(name__icontains='İ')
```

[image]

is there a way to search with like this?

By the way, I try to search with 'i.upper()' but this convert 'i' to 'I'. So this is not work for me.

Comment: `İ` is neither the capital of `i` nor is `I`.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19030948/python-utf-8-lowercase-turkish-specific-letter

Comment: @İsmet, you should get used to working with that character!

Comment: @Sam Yes, I exactly agree with you. But some situations push me that way sadly :(