# How to compare non-ASCII strings case-insensitive in Python?

Tags: python, string-comparison, case-insensitive

I want to compare two strings case-insensitive. In ASCII strings it's okey to use `string1.lower() == string2.lower()` and it works properly.

But with non-ASCII characters like Turkish `İ`, it doesn't work as it should. To show this with example,

```
string1 = 'insanlar'
string2 = "İnsanlar"
print(string1.lower() == string2.lower()) # returns false but they are same words
```

How to achieve this task with non-ASCII characters?

Comment: Have you tried [`locale.setlocale()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/locale.html#locale.setlocale)?

Comment: This is hard (the so-called ["Turkey Test"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/796986/3001761)) because it's context-dependent. In some languages, the lowercase of `"I"` is `"i"`, but they're not paired the same way in Turkish text.

Comment: Many thanks to deceze for pointing out that comparing `casefold()` outputs doesn't work here (I deleted my answer quickly to avoid showing incorrect information, so can't respond there).

Comment: Similar: [Python UTF-8 Lowercase Turkish Specific Letter](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19030948/3890632)

Comment: I guess that the reason *why* casefold doesn't work is that there is some strict lower-case equivalent of `İ` (`i̇`) which is not actually used here because it is easier just to use the ASCII `i`.

Comment: I don't know is it a reasonable solution but `unidecode(string2.lower()) == unidecode(string1.lower())` works.

Comment: PyICU's casefold method provides a parameter that can activate the Turkic casefolding rules provided in Unicode.